# mypy "invalid type" error

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to implement type annotations in a current project, and am receiving errors from mypy that I don't understand.

I'm using Python 2.7.11, and newly installed mypy in my base virtualenv.  The following program runs fine:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from types import StringTypes
from typing import List, Union, Callable

def f(value):     # type: (StringTypes) -> StringTypes
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("{}".format(f('some text')))
    print("{}".format(f(u'some unicode text')))
```

But running `mypy --py2 -s mypy_issue.py` returns the following:

```
mypy_issue.py: note: In function "f":
mypy_issue.py:8: error: Invalid type "types.StringTypes"
```

The above types appear to be in [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2.7/types.pyi)... the mypy [documentation](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=typeshed) says "Mypy incorporates the typeshed project, which contains library stubs for the Python builtins and the standard library. "... Not sure what "incorporates" means - do I need to do something to "activate", or provide a path to, Typeshed?  Do I need to download and install(?) Typeshed locally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `types.StringTypes` is defined to be a *sequence* of types -- the formal type signature [on Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2.7/types.pyi#L22) is:

```
StringTypes = (StringType, UnicodeType)
```

This corresponds to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.StringTypes), which states that the `StringTypes` constant is "a sequence containing `StringType` and `UnicodeType`"...

So then, this explains the error you're getting -- `StringTypes` isn't an actual class (it's probably a tuple) and so mypy doesn't recognize it as a valid type.

There are several possible fixes for this.

The first way would probably be to use `typing.AnyStr` which is defined as `AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)`. Although `AnyStr` is included within the `typing` module, it is, unfortunately, somewhat poorly documented as of now -- you can find more detailed information about what it does [within the mypy docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html?highlight=anystr#type-variables-with-value-restriction).

A slightly less cleaner way of expression this would be to do:

```
from types import StringType, UnicodeType
from typing import Union

MyStringTypes = Union[StringType, UnicodeType]

def f(value):     
    # type: (MyStringTypes) -> MyStringTypes
    return value
```

This also works, but is less desirable because the return type is no longer obligated to be the same thing as the input type which is usually not what you want when working with different kinds of strings.

And as for typeshed -- it's bundled by default when you install mypy. In an ideal world, you shouldn't need to worry about typeshed at all, but since mypy is in beta and so typeshed is being frequently updated to account for missing modules or incorrect type annotations, it might be worth installing mypy directly from the [Github repo](https://github.com/python/mypy) and installing typeshed locally if you find yourself frequently running into bugs with typeshed.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SolomonUcko -- No. The problem is that the `types` standard library module predates type hints and are really more for runtime use, rather then type hinting use. Despite the name, mypy (and any other PEP 484 compliant type checker) will not recognize `StringTypes` as a valid type: it's treated as ultimately being just a tuple that happens to contain two types. My recommendation is to avoid using anything from the `types` module in the context of type hints. Instead, use things from the `typing` module whenever possible -- so in this case, either `typing.AnyStr` or `Union[str, typing.Text]`.